# Attribute error when module imports itself - works on some computers

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have inherited some python scripts that I am trying to run. These include some custom modules and I get an error when importing one of them, which seems to be due to one of the modules importing itself. What I find strange is that it works on one computer, but not on another computer.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/path/to/packages/python_packages/x
                              |
/path/to/packages/python_packages/x/mod1.py
/path/to/packages/python_packages/x/mod2.py
/path/to/packages/python_packages/x/mod3.py
```

I add (and cross-check using print(sys.path)) the path as follows:

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/packages/python_packages/")
```

Then I do:

```
import x.mod1 as mod1
import x.mod2 as mod2
import x.mod3 as mod3
```

Importing mod1 works.

Importing mod2 does not work:

```
AttributeError: module 'x' has no attribute mod2
```

Traceback complains about this line, present in mod2.py:

```
import x.mod2 as mod2
```

Importing mod3 does not work, as it needs to import mod2, which it does in the same way as above.

In the traceback from ipython I can see that it finds the correct python files, since it prints out the code from the files and their names, full paths.

I have tried removing all **init**.py and **pycache**.

I tried running it on another computer, and there I can import the modules without any issues.

On the computer with the problem, I have Python 3.6.8, running on CentOS7 (3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64) and on the computer where it works, I have Python 3.9.2, running on Manjaro (5.4.108-1-MANJARO).

I do not have root access on the computer with the problem.

The full traceback is as follows (I changed path and file names to be consistent with above explanation):

```
In [9]: import x.mod2 as mod2
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8c4b062c2395> in <module>
----> 1 import x.mod2 as mod2

/path/to/packages/python_packages/x/mod2.py in <module>
  2 import numpy  as np
  3 
----> 4 import x.mod2 as mod2
  5 
  6 

AttributeError: module 'x' has no attribute 'mod2'
```

Comment: Why does the module need to import itself?

Comment: @aaron It imports itself in order to access the path one level up from where it is placed.
reference_path = "/".join(mod2.__file__.split("/")[0:-2]+["reference/"])

Comment: Changing this to a hard-coded path and removing the self-import works around the problem, but I would rather leave the code as is and solve whatever is prohibiting the self-import.

Comment: @a20 You should be able to use `__file__` directly.

Comment: @aaron thanks a lot! that works great and as far as I can see is sufficient in my case. However, for the sake of the community, I will leave the question open. The self-import should work, as it does on other computers.

Comment: @a20 I've posted that as an answer. There is no good reason for a module to import itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231845/discussion-between-a20-and-aaron).

Comment: @a20, i recommend formally "accepting" @ Daniel's answer. not that he's short on reputation points, but it's a nice thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to import `mod2` only to access `mod2.__file__`, since it is also available as `__file__`.

Instead of string fiddling you should use `pathlib`:

```
reference_path = Path(__file__).absolute().parents[2] / "reference"
```

Instead of using `as` use `from`:

```
from x import mod1
```

or, since you are already in the same package:

```
from . import mod1
```

Comment: noob question - are relative imports "ok" in packages? eg, if i am maintaining a library `foo`, and `foo/bar.py` needs stuff from `foo/baz.py`, is it good practice to have `from . import baz` in `foo/bar.py`? asking because i remember reading that relative imports were maybe bad / discouraged. but, without them, i don't know how to use absolute imports if the package root isn't visible in the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2):

> It imports itself in order to access the path one level up from where it is placed.
> `reference_path = "/".join(mod2.__file__.split("/")[0:-2]+["reference/"])`

You should be able to use `__file__` directly.